# Having a problem installing zeormq for python

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm a beginner on unix so I'm sorry if I post something easy. Also I have to admit that I do not master all the process.

I need to install zeromq on my ubuntu.

I have python 2.6.6 installed

I followed the instructions on the website for UNIX systems : http://www.zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software and after http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:python.

Precisely I did :

- Install libtool, autoconf, automake and uuid-dev
- Downloading the stable release
- sudo ./configure , sudo make, sudo make install and sudo ldconfig

(At this point I don't get any error)

But when I type : sudo easy_install pyzmq
I get the error :

> zmq/core/constants.c:4: fatal error:
>   Python.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated. 
>   error: command
>   'gcc' failed with exit status 1

I get the same error if I try to install manually.

I don't know what to do at this point and I can't find somebody having the same problem.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the error you gave us is saying that gcc failed. Most likely gcc also gave you a *long* error message telling you *why* it failed. That is more helpful.

If I'm going to guess, some sort of development headers is missing. Probably the Python development headers, which you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

But exactly what it wrong can only be answered when you give the relevant error message (which in C/C++ annoyingly comes in the beggining or the error message).

Comment: I installed python-dev and there wasn't error anymore. Thank you !

Comment: This solution also works for other packages trying to be compiled without the development headers in the system, and producing the same gcc output error. Thanks.

Comment: in the ipython installation page, it would be helpful to share this tip, it includes already a list of dependency libraries, not this one.

Comment: @igni: It's not a dependency library, it's the Python header files. That it requires Python are implicit.